# ActionBarSherlock and fragments

Tags: android, events, onclick, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I got an application with one hosting activity, where lots of fragments are hosted one at a time. Also I got a way to navigate between them. What I want is to change buttons on the top of an actionbar to fit currently shown fragment and to implement listeners for the onClick events of those buttons. The problem is that there will be lots of different button types ( different for the fragment which is show. Is there any way to somehow catch those event (onClick) in a fragment?